# Disable Home and other ribbons tabs in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

We want to disable some of the ribbons tabs in Excel using VBA. But are unable to do so using VBA.

We found out this below code but it hides the whole ribbon tab. But we want some of the controls to be enabled like Filters Fonts etc.

```
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"", False)"
```

Comment: Have a look at [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386097.aspx) to be able to customize the ribbon. Then also look at [this as well](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win012.htm) to be able to customize the default ribbon